# Regx for correct filename 1201_17-11-2015.zip

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to check whether a given file name is in the correct format or not.

Means:

```
first four numbers_two numbers-two numbers-4 numbers.zip
```

for that I need a regular expression. 
Example file name is (1201_17-11-2015.zip) in javascript

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please show reasonable research and effort, and provide code sample.

Answer (score 3):

```
var re = new RegExp('^\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}.zip$');
if (filename.match(re)) {
    //successful match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You regexp could look something like this:

```
^\d{4}_\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}.zip$
```

^ is the beginning of your pattern
\d means any number
{n} means that the last pattern has to exist n-time
$ is the end of your pattern

On [this site](http://regexone.com/) you can start learning how to use regular expression
[Here](https://regex101.com/) you can test if your own regular expression is working...

Answer (score 2):

I find it best to test scenarios at [RegExr](http://regexr.com/). None the less, what you're asking for is basic:

```
var result = "1201_17-11-2015.zip".match(/\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.zip/)
if (result == null) {
    console.warn("Unable to find a match");
} else {
    console.log("Found match: %k", result);
}
```